# Converting unlocked package to managed package

Tags: managed-package, unlocked-package

Is it possible to convert an unlocked package to a managed package? If so, how?

Context: I am developing a 2GP unlocked package but want to make it managed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would install the unlocked package to a developer org, create a new managed package, and add the components to it. There's no direct mechanism for conversion, but the process of creating the package would be trivial. You can also continue using the unlocked package to push updates to the managed package as needed.

Comment: In the same vein, could you use unlocked packages to deploy to a developer org that already has a managed package?  I'd like to develop new functionality in unlocked package units as part of a greater managed package, and it would be nice to keep development of each feature separate and push upgrades into the final managed package

Comment: @BrianMiller Yes, that's perfectly possible, and an intended use case. What you'd do is set the namespace for each unlocked package to that of the managed package. Instructions for doing this are in the documentation.

Comment: Amazing.  I'm assuming even if the unlocked packages had no namespace - if you added them to the managed package itself, that would also work?  I like keeping the unlocked packages without a namespace as we beta test with our internal production org

Comment: @BrianMiller By my understanding, it should work. I would try it with a throwaway org to make sure, though. The best practice recommendation is to use the namespace rather than not.